# Netstat doesn't work on FreeBSD by php function exec()

Tags: php, freebsd, netstat

In my php-app I need the list of all IP's connected on port 80. I've chosen to do it this way:

```
<?php
     $ips = exec("netstat -an |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c", $info);
?>
```

But it doesn't work on my VPS FreeBSD server. When I start `netstat -an` a notice appears and no connections are in output:

```
netstat: kvm not available: /dev/mem: No such file or directory
```

I tried to add `device mem` to conf, but I have an empty /usr/src/sys. I got to the point that I need to rebuild the core.))

`netstat` works correctly when user is root (from console). I haven't had any problems like this on a similar CentOS hosting platform.

Fot resolving `/dev/mem: No such file or directory` I've tried to do `mknod -m 660 /dev/mem c 1 1` but it calls an `mknod: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted`

I've got the following users `pw showuser`

```
owl:*:1000:1003:default:0:0:owl:/home/owl/data:/bin/csh
root:*:0:0::0:0:Charlie &:/root:/bin/csh
```

Summary:
When I run `netstat` as `owl` - it returns an empty list of connections
When I run `netstat` as `root` - it returns notice `netstat: kvm not available: /dev/mem: No such file or directory` and IP's

Can anybody help me? Is there maybe another way that exists for resolving this task? Thank you

Comment: Does your `netstat` have similar group permissions: -r-xr-sr-x 1 root kmem 88780 Aug 23 2007 /usr/bin/netstat ? — It's to be kmem SGIDed to gain needed priveleges when run by non-privileged users.

Comment: Regarding the empty /usr/src/sys. To rebuild the FreeBSD core on your VPS you need to synchronize the source tree, add the options and devices you want to add to the kernel. This is all described in the FreeBSD handbook:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/makeworld.html

Comment: i have permission `netstat` like you wrote for my user

Comment: @AndreiZhamoida, bring `ls -l` into the studio, please.

Comment: I've changed group from `kmem` to `wheel` but notice is not hide
`vm# ls -la netstat    
-r-xr-sr-x  1 root  wheel  157616 Apr 28 18:51 netstat`

Comment: i added more info in my question above

Comment: AFAIK, some custom FreeBSD based VDS solutions like firstvds.ru have some weird bugs and limitations like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your `cut` is not behaving as you expect, since in `netstat`'s output, the IP and port are separated by a dot, not a colon.

I also get a `netstat: kvm not available: /dev/mem: No such file or directory` error when I run `netstat -an` within some of the jails I administer, but despite this error, I still get expected results from netstat.  I haven't researched why this occurs, so I'm leaning towards thinking that this is a red herring.

In terms of your command line, you can reduce your plumbing by packing more functionality into the awk script:

```sh
netstat -an | \
  awk '/^(tcp|udp)/{ip=$5; sub(/.[0-9]+$/,"",ip); list[ip]++;} END{for(ip in list){printf("%7d %s\n",list[ip],ip)}}'
```

Split up for easier reading, this awk script is:

```sh
# Only work on tcp/udp lines...
/^(tcp|udp)/ {
  ip=$5;
  sub(/.[0-9]+$/,"",ip);
  list[ip]++;  # Populate an array of counters-per-IP
}

# After data are gathered, print the results.
END {
  for (ip in list) {
    printf("%7d %s\n",list[ip],ip);
  }
}
```

But since you're doing this in PHP, I'd do more of this text processing in PHP.

```php
<?php

# Gather our data...
exec("netstat -an", $out);

# Easy access to the output we want (for isset() below)
$permit = array("udp4"=>1,"tcp4"=>1);

foreach ($out as $line) {

  $a = preg_split("/[[:space:]]+/", $line);

  # Only work on tcp4/udp4 lines...
  if (isset($permit[$a[0]])) {
    # Populate an array of counters...
    $ip = substr($a[4], 0, strrpos($a[4],".")-1);
    $list[$ip]++;
  }

}

# And print the results.
foreach ($list as $ip => $count) {
  printf("%7s\t%s\n", $count, $ip);
}
```

This may seem like more work, but it may actually be faster than spawning a collection of pipes.

Note that you also have the `sockstat` command in FreeBSD, so building on Chris S's suggestion:

```php
<?php

exec("sockstat -4", $out);

$permit = array("udp4"=>1,"tcp4"=>1);

foreach ($out as $line) {

  $a = preg_split("/[[:space:]]+/", $line);

  if (isset($permit[$a[4]])) {
    preg_match("/^[^:]+/", $a[6], $ip);
    $list[$ip[0]]++;
  }

}

foreach ($list as $ip => $count) {
  printf("%7s\t%s\n", $count, $ip);
}
```

***UPDATE:***

I also came across [this ancient note about the kvm error](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2005-February/011799.html).  Since routing table information is *usually* available, you should contact your VPS provider and find out whether they have intentionally restricted your access to routing table data on this host.  If you are not in a jail, then I suspect that a post to one of the FreeBSD mailing lists would get results.  There's also a ##FreeBSD channel at irc.freenode.net where knowledgeable people often hang out.